# (Py)OpenCl: wrong scan result after 16th element

Tags: opencl

So I've started working on a *Hillis - Steele* scan algorithm so get the running sum of an array, and it seems to work fine for arrays with less than 17 elements (`N < 17`), but after that I often get incorrect results, though not always. The larger `N`, the higher probability of returning an incorrect result, which gets to 100% incorrectness after `N = 40` or so. The array starts to deviate from the true values after the 16th element.

Here's my code:

```
__kernel void scan(__global double * a, __const int N, __global double * sum_a, __global double * temp) {

    //
    // Hillis - Steele scan algorithm
    //

    int id = get_global_id(0); // Thread id

    temp[id] = a[id]; // Copying the content of a to a temporary array
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); // Waiting for all threads to finish

    for(int offset = 1; offset < N; offset *= 2) { // At each increment, double 'offset'

        if(id >= offset)
            temp[id] += temp[id - offset]; // Add 'id' to a neighbour a distance 'offset' away
        else
            temp[id] = temp[id]; // Copy the previous value

        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE); // Synchronising
    }
    sum_a[id] = temp[id]; // Storing final result
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenCL, you can only synchronize between work items in a work group, not globally. Your kernel appears to depend on global synchronization.

Comment: I thought `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)` synchronised between all threads, as opposed to the `barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE)`? Do you have any suggestions to make it work properly?

Comment: CLK_GLOBAL/LOCAL_MEM_FENCE has to do with the *kind* of memory being synchronized, not the *scope* of the synchronization (it's *always* only within the work group). The only way to do global synchronization is to have separate kernels. So split your kernel (at the points you have syncs) into multiple kernels and queue them each up. The second kernel won't start until all work groups of the first finshes.